# Openshift route does not work without trailing slash

Tags: routes, openshift, kubernetes-ingress

I am using Openshift 4.3 and I have created route with hostname and path like below

```
kind: Route
apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
metadata:
  name: mts-poc-api
  namespace: dev
  labels:
    app: mts-poc-api
spec:
  host: >-
    mts-poc-dev.mts-prep-78dhjnd76sg5678njs92hdh-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud
  path: /mts-api/
  to:
    kind: Service
    name: mts-poc-api-dev-service
    weight: 100
  port:
    targetPort: mts-poc-api-http
  tls:
    termination: edge
    insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
```

I launch app using `mts-poc-dev.mts-prep-78dhjnd76sg5678njs92hdh-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud/mts-api/` which launches app correctly but if I remove trailing slash and use `mts-poc-dev.mts-prep-78dhjnd76sg5678njs92hdh-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud/mts-api`it does not work it gives
Application is not available

```
The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.
```

I want application to get launched even if I dont append / to route. Is there a way? because in Openshift 3.11 we were using Ingress and it was working perfectly the way we want.

Comment: You have the path specified as `/mts-api/`, have you tried dropping the trailing `/` from your Route definition?

Comment: yes I tried that as well

Comment: Not for nothing, but you've confirmed the route was _accepted_ without the trailing `/`, right? Just wanted to rule out an already existing route preventing the change from being picked up

Comment: On OpenShift 4, we use the bare path (e.g. "/path") without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

What might help is removing the path parameter. So, the route would point only to the host, and would not specify further matching.

Without the path part, anything hitting the `mts-poc-dev.mts-prep-78dhjnd76sg5678njs92hdh-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud` host will get through. Your application should then be available at `mts-poc-dev.mts-prep-78dhjnd76sg5678njs92hdh-0000.us-south.containers.appdomain.cloud/mts-api`.

The disadvantage is that no other application can be bound to the host, unless you do some advanced routing (like with Istio, which is Service Mesh in the OpenShift world)

Comment: we are using same host for several apps but with different path so we need path here.